# How send mail without using MFmailViewController pop up view?

Tags: iphone

I am New to iPhone developer i dont know how to add this application .

Answer (score 0):

I think you question has been asked a number of times here on SO. Check out similar questions and answers.

Also check http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/ which is a library for sending mail directly through an SMTP server.